# Hoverstate on parent jQuery script works only one way

Tags: jquery, mouseover, addclass, removeclass, mouseout

I want my parent items in the navigation to have the hover or active state when I hover over child items.

So I looked around and found out that I can use jQuery to accomplish this. Made this script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $nav = $('#productnav ul.sub-menu li');
    $nav.mouseover(function() {
            $("#productnav ul.sf-menu li.deeper").addClass(' overstate ')
        }
  );
    $nav.mouseleave(function() {
            $("#productnav ul .sf-menu li.deeper").removeClass(' overstate ')
        }
  );
}); 
</script>
```

After a few hours (and reading a lot), I got it to work. Partially.

The class is added to the parent, works fine. But it is not removed. Tried to make this with the hover method from jQuery with the same result.

Anybody know what's wrong in this script?

Regards, Hans

Comment: make it live ... $nav.on('mouseleave'){}

Comment: Hi Florin, I'm not sure what you mean with "make it live". Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

check this:

$("#productnav ul.sf-menu li.deeper")
$("#productnav ul .sf-menu li.deeper")

try to remove the blank space between "ul" and ".sf" of your second selector.

The rest of the code looks fine and should work.

Comment: O yes! After fiddling around for hours, you don't see anything anymore. This was the (simple) solution! Thanks.